# Service function undefined in AngulajJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am starting to learn AngularJS, and am trying to call a service method from a controller. But when I am calling it, it is saying the function is undefined.

The strange thing is when I print the service object in console, I can see the function. Yet when I try to call it, it says undefined.

**Controller**

```
(function() {
angular.module('public')
.controller('NewPatientController', NewPatientController);

NewPatientController.$inject = ['NewPatientService'];
function NewPatientController(NewPatientService) {
    var $ctrl = this;
    console.log(NewPatientService.register1);
    $ctrl.mess = 'hhtg';
    $ctrl.success = null;
    NewPatientService.regsiter1();
    $ctrl.submit = function() {
        console.log('Ctrl');
        NewPatientService.regsiter1();

    }

}

})();
```

**Service**

(function () {
    angular.module('public')
    .service('NewPatientService', NewPatientService);

```
function NewPatientService() {
    var service = this;
    service.userInfo = null;
    this.register1 = function () {

    }
}

})();
```

The exact error I get is:

```
NewPatientService.regsiter1 is not a function
```

Can someone please point out what might be the issue in this.

Comment: You have created register1 and are trying to call regsiter1. Please fix the spelling.

Comment: @NikhileshKV Thanks, silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the line `console.log(NewPatientService.register1);`

Try to remove or change it as follows

```
console.log(NewPatientService.register1());
```

Also there is a issue on the line  `NewPatientService.regsiter1();` after console.log,

it should be `NewPatientService.register1();`

Comment: The line you are pointing is working fine, with output as:
function () {
            
        }

Comment: are you still getting the issue?

Comment: there is a spelling issue it should be register1